# AWS Lambda package dependencies failing to load

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cryptography

I am trying to use an API sdk to interact with a some software through AWS Lambda.
I have packaged the dependencies correctly by zipping the pip installed packages in the correct directly structure:
`/opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/` and uploaded them as a layer.
I am confident of this because I am able to successfully import requests, one of the sdk's dependencies in the zip file.
The error I get, when trying to import the sdk or cryptography its self:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /opt/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I have unzipped the zipped layer file and can see the `_rust.abi3.so` file present in the directory stated in the error. I am creating the zip file on an Ubuntu image spun up through Docker.

I have tried using different versions of Python (3.6,3.7).
I have attempted creating the layer both manually and through the code [here](https://github.com/soumilshah1995/create-aws-layers-for-python-lambda/blob/main/etl.py).

I am using x86_64 Architecture, Python 3.9, pip3

Comment: You should use lambda container images, if you have dependencies on *.so files. Its much easier to manage them this way.